# Deleted categories still listed until additional page refresh

Tags: categories, customization

I've tried using `wp_delete_category()` and `wp_delete_term()` to delete a category, but after the page reloads, the deleted category still shows up in the results of `get_categories()`. But if I reload the page a second time, the category is gone.

How can I make sure it goes away after the first reload?

---

I'm grabbing form data with a `$_POST` and handing to `wp_delete_category()`. This is all taking place on a plugin settings page.  Here's a little snippet of my code.  Suggestions welcome.

```
if ( isset($_POST['deleteSelectedCategories']) ){

    $cats = $_POST['catsToDelete'];
    $catsArray = explode(',', $cats);

    foreach ($catsArray as $catID) {
        // wp_delete_category( $catID );        
        wp_delete_term( $catID, 'category' );
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any caching plugins active on that site? Does your hosting use any caches?

Comment: No caching plugins installed and nothing in the cpanel.  Any other changes I make show up right away.  Basically, no evidence of caching as far as I can tell.

Comment: When exactly are you running `wp_delete_category()`? In what context?

Comment: @JacobPeattie I'm calling it from a plugin settings page.  I've updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a workaround by forcing the second refresh, but I'm sure there's probably a better way to do this.

In order to make the process smoother for the user, I'm thinking I'll have to do an AJAX post and then refresh on success to show the updated data.

---

```
if ( isset($_POST['deleteSelectedCategories']) ){

    $cats = $_POST['catsToDelete'];
    $catsArray = explode(',', $cats);

    $success = 0;

    foreach ($catsArray as $catID) {
        if ( wp_delete_term( $catID, 'category' ) ) {
            $success++;
        }
    }

    if ($success > 0) {
        echo '[Here I have some HTML to block out the screen 
            and show a message to the user, 
            and then the following meta refresh:] 
            <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0" />';
    }
}
```